# Is mean value theorem for real valued function is hold for complex valued function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Is mean value theorem for real valued function  hold for complex valued function?

Answer (score 2):

No, in general you won't find $\xi$ in $[a,b]$ so that $f'(\xi) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. The reason is simple: the said $\xi$ should satisfy the equalities for the real and the imaginary part, and the same $\xi$ will not work for both( in general).

Comment: Can you give an explicit example for illustration, please?

Comment: @Freeze_S: Yes, take $f(t)= e^{ i t}$. Then $f(0) = f(2\pi) =1$ but $|f'(t)|=1$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$